# Print Canvas wrap with 3D perspective preview

Tags: php, jquery, css, gd, perspective

I am looking for something that would allow me to render an uploaded image with a 3D perspective and a wrap effect like [here](http://dustinizatt.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/CanvasOnDemandPromoimage1-image1-1219939535.jpg).

This will be in the form of a cropping preview using a jQuery library such as jCrop

Currently I was able to achieve the 3D perspective using [Reflex.js](http://www.netzgesta.de/reflex/) but looking for a more subtle solution with the wrapping effect as well.

Any help will be appreciated :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What browser need to be supported? so far your approach locks out internet explorer all together.

Comment: This should atleast support all the Grade A browsers. Latest versions of Firefox, Chrome and IE 9

Comment: Then you may want to consider doing it in canvas tag. Its going to be a lot of work, and I would resist the urge to include any plugins at all.

Comment: @Fresheyeball, the Reflex.js that I mentioned about is rendering the image in a canvas. I am able to achieve the 3D perspective of the image but I need the wrap effect as well which is not directly achievable. I tried by cropping a part of the image and then merging it back to the original but cannot get a finished effect :(

Comment: I know Reflex.js works with canvas. I am saying its the wrong approach to rely on libraries for this one. Its going to be more work, for less quality, cobbling together existing libraries to make this work. You should learn to write the canvas tag at a native level and make your own plugin. What you want is just not that economical.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement of IE9 support basically mandates a canvas approach if you want to keep it client-side. You could of course do the rendering server-side and AJAX load the rendered image back in which will work in every browser.

If you decide that you can dump IE versions less than 10 (or at least just show them the normal photo without the transform then you can do the wrap-around effect with a combination of CSS 3D Transforms and CSS2 clip. Something like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<style>
  body { margin: 100px; position: relative; }
  .edge { width: 20px; height: 196px; background-size: auto 100%; position: absolute; left: 30px; top: 2px; transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(-45deg); transform-origin: right; }
  .panel {  position: absolute; left: 31px; top: 0; clip: rect(auto,auto,auto,20px); }
  .panel>img { width: 350px; height: 200px; transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(30deg); transform-origin: left; }
</style>
<div class="edge" style="background-image: url(my_image.jpg)"></div>
<div class="panel"><img src="my_image.jpg" /></div>
```

To break that down, we’ve loaded the user’s image and dropped it into the page, along with a `div` with the same image set as a background. That `div` is set to be a thin width and a height that’s almost as tall as the main image. We can use the `background-size` property to foce the background image to fit the `div` even if it’s taller.

We then absolutely position those two so that they’re next to each-other. The CSS2 `clip` property lets us clip off the left 20px of the image so that at this point the `div` and `img` look like one image together.

Finally, we set a `perspective` and `transform-origin` for each block and rotate them away from each-other around the Y axis. Because of the clipping we have to fudge the `.edge` block to be slightly smaller than originally (with a 200px tall image I had to drop it to 196px to look good) but that works pretty nicely for me.

Obviously you’d need to fill in the vendor prefixes (-moz-, -ms-, -o-, -webkit) and I’ll leave the shadow as an exercise for the reader (a simple background on the container would probably do).